# vc++ mktime make wrong month number

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I can't figure out what mistake I did i the following code but using visual c++ 2010 sp1 the result of the code as I pasted below shows one month mistake.

```
struct tm timeStamp;
timeStamp.tm_year = 2012 - 1900;
timeStamp.tm_mon = 7;
timeStamp.tm_mday = 19;
timeStamp.tm_hour = 20;
timeStamp.tm_min = 55;
timeStamp.tm_sec = 22;
timeStamp.tm_isdst = -1;


time_t time_val = mktime(&timeStamp);

const int buff_size = 20;
char buff[buff_size] = {0};
strftime(buff, buff_size, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime( &time_val ));


cout << "Original time:\t"
    << timeStamp.tm_year + 1900 << "-" << timeStamp.tm_mon << "-" << timeStamp.tm_mday << " "
    << timeStamp.tm_hour << ":" << timeStamp.tm_min << ":" << timeStamp.tm_sec << endl;
cout << "Converted time:\t" << buff << endl;
```

and the output result for this code as I compile is:

```
Original time:  2012-7-19 20:55:22
Converted time: 2012-08-19 20:55:22
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tm_mon` field of `struct tm` is from `0-11`, where 0 == January and 11 == December. `strftime` knows this and compensates internally. your `cout` doesn't compensate for this.

The [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/) page for `struct tm` contains the definition of the ranges of all the values.

Comment: OK, Thanks . That made me a lot of problem. I wonder why most of c++ libraries made different approaches e.g. TIMESTAMP_STRUCT in Visual c++  libraries range the month field between 1-12. that makes confusings.

Comment: That's why you have to read the documentation instead of guessing. Often the standard library (and even worse for third-party libraries) does thing in ways that don't seem like the most obvious "right" way, and sometimes even inconsistently, often for historical reasons.

Comment: tm_mon ranging from 0 - 11 allows it to be used directly as an index into an array of month name strings.

Comment: Why they did not range the day field from [0-30] and make it [1-31] I am very anxious to know about this if it has any historical reason.

Comment: As @RobK mentioned; it's an easy index into array of string names. It's actually stated as 'months since January' rather than month of year.

Comment: @AMCoded, you would not use tm_mday as an index into an array of strings. You'll notice that tm_wday, which indicates the day of the week, also begins its range at 0 [0 - 6]. This field would be used to index an array containing the names of the days of the week.